# Get Informed by E-mail after an database change or an event in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have a PayPal button to pay for an item. Every time the button appears I generate in `PHP` a `UUID` and add it to the button with tag `"custom"`.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" class="payPalBtn">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="b1890a0d-c7c6">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="WT1A5CCD4V1">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/he_IL/IL/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
</form>
```

After successful payment, PayPal redirect me to a page where this `UUID` number is sent back, so I know that for record X for example the payment is done. I update it in the server database and all fine. 
The question is how can I be informed by email after I change the status of item X to PAID. I need to know this as fast as it changed.

Comment: Since you're updating your database using PHP, is there a reason you couldn't just add an email snippet right after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. It's as simple as implementing:

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

into the same location where you're updating the database.

For an example visit [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Remember to close/end your function with a semi-colon (`;`) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have PHP send a mail in the file that updates your database?